# First record start date, last record end date for contract of each user, and how to apply filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm in a bit over my head here. I've got a table with the contract information of all employees. An employee can have multiple contracts in this table as everytime they get promoted, or are up for renewal, a new contract will be made. Apart from that there's the possibility that an employee leaves the company for any period of time, so there may be gaps between contracts.

There are two things I'm trying to achieve:

- The average time employees stay on each jobgrade
- Years of service, so length of each contract from an employee combined

  ```
  class Contract(models.Model):

      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
      employment = models.ForeignKey(Employment, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
      jobgrade = models.ForeignKey(Jobgrade, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
      contract_start = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
      contract_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
  ```

Comment: Does you need the solution to use the django ORM (so it can present the results inside the django app)?  What version of django are you using?If just querying with SQL for the answers is acceptable, what is the database that underlies it, sqlite, mysql, postgres...?

Comment: My view needs to pass the results to the template so I can show it in diagrams etc. Using latest Django version with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property method in your `Jobgrade` and `Employee` model classes like these:

```
class Jobgrade(models.Model):
   ...

   @property
   def average_time(self):
      # gets average time of of a Jobgrade
      return self.contract_set.all().annotate(diff=F('contract_start')-F('contract_end')).aggregate(avg=Avg('diff'))['avg']


class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def get_length(self):
       # gets sum time of of a Employee
       return self.contract_set.all().annotate(diff=F('contract_start')-F('contract_end')).aggregate(sum=Sum('diff'))['sum']
```

Here I am using [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) difference between two times using [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) expression. Then I used [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) to get [sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) and [average](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#avg).

Now you can use these values in template like:

```
{% for employee in Employee.objects.all %}
     {{ employee.get_length }}
{% endfor %}


{% for job in Jobgrade.objects.all %}
     {{ job.average_time }}
{% endfor %}
```